# Trying to convert list into array yields "error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Array' "

Tags: c#, arrays, list, error-handling

I'm new to C# comming from a python background. I'm currently trying to solve this [challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/544aed4c4a30184e960010f4) on codewars.com. It's about finding all the divisors to a number. I tried programming it in the following way, which is already an improved version of my code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60391439/getting-error-cs0246-the-type-or-namespace-name-list-could-not-be-found-w)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Kata
{  
  public static int[] Divisors(int n)
  {
    List<int> divisors = new List<int>();

    int i = 2, biggest_divisor = n;

    while (true)
    {
      if ( n % i == 0)
        {
          divisors.Add(i);
          divisors.Add(n/i);
          biggest_divisor = i;
        }

      if ( i > biggest_divisor)
        break;

      i++;
    }

    if (divisors.Count > 0)
    {
      divisors.ToArray();
      return Array.Sort(divisors);
    }
    else
      return null;
  }
}
```

When executing `if (divisors.Count > 0)` this yields the following error

> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Array'

Why does this error appear anyways, I'm just using methods on a list.

Comment: `divisors.ToArray` will not convert the current list to an array (this would imply an instance could change its runtime-type), but it **creates** a new  array, which the method would return. So you should assign the return-value of `ToArray` to a variable and use that within `Sort`.

Comment: Don't return `null` for collection types (arrays, lists, etc.). Return an empty set instead. And then you can remove the `> 0` check because you don't have to do anything different depending on whether there are any items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

```
  divisors.ToArray();
```

creates a *new* `int[]` array and *throws it away*. Then you try to sort *list* `divisors` (`List<int>`) as an *array*:

```
  // divisors is List<int>, not expected int[] 
  return Array.Sort(divisors);
```

and have the *compile time error*. Let's sort `divisors` and return it as an array in one go:

```
using System.Linq;

...

public static int[] Divisors(int n)
  {
    ...
    if (divisors.Count > 0)
    {
      // Order List, create an array from it and, finally, return the array
      return divisors.OrderBy(item => item).ToArray();
    }
    else
      //TODO: better return an empty array: return int[0]; 
      return null;
  }
```

Comment: Do I need to add something before `public static` ? This code yields the following error

Comment: error CS1061: 'List<int>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no accessible extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'List<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` at the top

Answer (score 2):

pass `divisors.ToArray();` to `Array.Sort(HERE);` it is expecting an `Array` not a `List<T>`

`divisors.ToArray()` does not mutate `divisors`, it returns a copy of the list converted to `Array` structure instead.

So:

```
if (divisors.Count > 0)
{
  divisors.ToArray();
  return Array.Sort(divisors);
}
```

Should be

```
if (divisors.Count > 0)
{
  var divisorsArray = divisors.ToArray();
  Array.Sort(divisorsArray);
  return divisorsArray;
}
```

And the error should be gone

btw, use do-while instead of While(true) and break.

Comment: I think you meant changing the part of the `if` statement to ` return Array.Sort(divisors.ToArray());`. This however yields `error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int[]'`

Comment: This is not right. Array.sort() will return void but his method is expecting int arrays

Comment: ok nevermind, commented before your edit. The error I mentioned stays however

Comment: That's why I'm returning `divisorsArray` after `Array.Sort` @madreflection

Comment: Do I have to know every method firm? I don't think so, do you code c# on notepad? Whats the point of using a strongly typed lang if I have to know all the firms. c'mon.

Comment: No, Knowing that a type can't change is not the same that knowing that some static methods modify the actual structure by reference instead of returning the result of their modifications, and others do not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ToArray() method returns a array, not transform the object in array.

To resolve that, you must to do following:

```cs
    if (divisors.Count > 0)
    {
      var divs = divisors.OrderBy().ToArray();
      return divs;
    }
```